# JS - filter an array (includes object) with an array

Tags: javascript

I think I don't understand how I can filter an object with an array.

I get this data from my mongoDB:

```
[{
    "_id": "5fed0cde68b6e7856dffb26c",
    "question": "Questions1",
    "answer1": "1",
    "isTrue1": true,
    "answer2": "2",
    "isTrue2": false,
    "answer3": "3",
    "isTrue3": false,
    "answer4": "4",
    "isTrue4": false,
    "category": ["5fed0fe768b6e7856d0244ea", "5ff0278968b6e7856d3d04cd"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ff47f6768b6e7856d121930",
    "question": "Questions1",
    "answer1": "1",
    "isTrue1": true,
    "answer2": "2",
    "isTrue2": false,
    "answer3": "3",
    "isTrue3": false,
    "answer4": "4",
    "isTrue4": false,
    "category": ["5fed0fe768b6e7856d0244ea", "5ff0278968b6e7856d3d04cd"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ff7190568b6e7856dba37c6",
    "question": "Questions1",
    "answer1": "1",
    "isTrue1": true,
    "answer2": "2",
    "isTrue2": false,
    "answer3": "3",
    "isTrue3": false,
    "answer4": "4",
    "isTrue4": false,
    "category": ["5ff8d51668b6e7856dd0ce9b", "5ff8d51f68b6e7856dd0d3f5"]
  }
]
```

And now I would like filter the data with this array (the numbers are the value of "_id"):

```
[5fed0cde68b6e7856dffb26c,5ff47f6768b6e7856d121930]
```

I expect the first two objects of the mongoDB-Data.

Can someone explain and help me with the problem?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Use `filter()` to filter the array, and use `search_array.includes(element._id)` in the test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

As in the commentarys mentioned you can use Arrays filter function.

Inside filter you can build a condition with the includes method so check if you your searchID' array includes the new id

```js
    const objects = [{
        "_id": "5fed0cde68b6e7856dffb26c",
        "question": "Questions1",
        "answer1": "1",
        "isTrue1": true,
        "answer2": "2",
        "isTrue2": false,
        "answer3": "3",
        "isTrue3": false,
        "answer4": "4",
        "isTrue4": false,
        "category": ["5fed0fe768b6e7856d0244ea", "5ff0278968b6e7856d3d04cd"]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ff47f6768b6e7856d121930",
        "question": "Questions1",
        "answer1": "1",
        "isTrue1": true,
        "answer2": "2",
        "isTrue2": false,
        "answer3": "3",
        "isTrue3": false,
        "answer4": "4",
        "isTrue4": false,
        "category": ["5fed0fe768b6e7856d0244ea", "5ff0278968b6e7856d3d04cd"]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ff7190568b6e7856dba37c6",
        "question": "Questions1",
        "answer1": "1",
        "isTrue1": true,
        "answer2": "2",
        "isTrue2": false,
        "answer3": "3",
        "isTrue3": false,
        "answer4": "4",
        "isTrue4": false,
        "category": ["5ff8d51668b6e7856dd0ce9b", "5ff8d51f68b6e7856dd0d3f5"]
      }
    ]
    const searchKeywords = ["5fed0cde68b6e7856dffb26c","5ff47f6768b6e7856d121930"]

    
    let resultObj = objects.filter(val => searchKeywords.includes(val._id))
   


    console.log(resultObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Set` from the the array of ids and filter the data based on it.

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"5fed0cde68b6e7856dffb26c","question":"Questions1","answer1":"1","isTrue1":true,"answer2":"2","isTrue2":false,"answer3":"3","isTrue3":false,"answer4":"4","isTrue4":false,"category":["5fed0fe768b6e7856d0244ea","5ff0278968b6e7856d3d04cd"]},
{"_id":"5ff47f6768b6e7856d121930","question":"Questions1","answer1":"1","isTrue1":true,"answer2":"2","isTrue2":false,"answer3":"3","isTrue3":false,"answer4":"4","isTrue4":false,"category":["5fed0fe768b6e7856d0244ea","5ff0278968b6e7856d3d04cd"]},
{"_id":"5ff7190568b6e7856dba37c6","question":"Questions1","answer1":"1","isTrue1":true,"answer2":"2","isTrue2":false,"answer3":"3","isTrue3":false,"answer4":"4","isTrue4":false,"category":["5ff8d51668b6e7856dd0ce9b","5ff8d51f68b6e7856dd0d3f5"]}]
const set = new Set(['5fed0cde68b6e7856dffb26c','5ff47f6768b6e7856d121930']);
const res = arr.filter(({_id})=>set.has(_id));
console.log(res);
```